# If someone falls asleep in Animagus form, would they change back?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

Being an Animagus takes a lot of magical energy but since you’re asleep it's not like you lose energy, you just lose concentration? And since (idk where I read it but I read it somewhere) some people become animals so they can have freedom, like run around or whatever, they wouldn't hold that much concentration, **would you automatically turn back into a human while you sleep because you’re not concentrating on staying in animal form?**

I think no because you're still alive and if you're a strong wizard or witch you'd still have a strong enough magical presence to hold it but I'm not sure.

Comment: No.  Staying in animal form when asleep is a HUGE requirement of the main plot of one book.  (And while this is the answer, it really needs to be answered _correctly_ by people who won't leave spoilers, and will be able to find the relevant parts of the books and movie scenes.)

Comment: It is not stated in any canon material of HP world that maintaining the animal form takes a lot of energy. It is hard to achieve and to learn, but we don't know how energy consuming is it.

Comment: Note to close voters: we don't close questions as primarily opinion-based just because the answer is "we don't know". In fact, in this case we *do* know the answer, as shown by the answers below.

Comment: `Being an Animagus takes a lot of magical energy` ~> Any citation? Also, define `Magical Energy`..

Comment: It might be some effort to transform in and out of animal form (I don't remember anything on that though), but I'm pretty sure it didn't seem like maintaining form took any effort at all. Pettigrew for example, didn't seem to be "weakened" after transforming back in PoA, despite being a rat for many years.

Comment: I’ve edited your question to avoid the title and the body asking opposite questions, which gets confusing. If someone answers ‘yes’ or ‘no’, it’s best if that answer means the same thing to the question in the title and the one in the body of the question.

Comment: I have downvoted this because I feel that it shows lack of understanding/basic knowledge of the canon books or story. Plenty of references are made to a certain animagus sleeping (particularly that that's all he seems to do).

Comment: It takes energy on the switch between forms, not to sustain the transformation (check the answers below for the canon references), unlike other transformations like Metamorphmagus or the plant-based Polyjuice and Gillyweed (which eat up a set amount of magical energy) or regular transformation (cf. Viktor Krum in the second task in GoF).

Comment: @mirabilos There is no evidence for that. We don’t know how much ‘magic energy’ is required to transform once you’ve learnt how. You also seem to be saying that it takes energy to sustain transformations brought on by Metamorphmagicking, drinking Polyjuice Potion, or chewing Gillyweed, which is almost certainly false based on the books’ descriptions.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it’s certainly correct based on the books’ descriptions: Polyjuice, etc. last for a certain amount of time, after which the energy holding the transformation is spent, and so it reverts.

Comment: @mirabilos Ah, I see what you mean now. You’re talking about what we might call ‘cosmic/absolute’ energy, rather than ‘individual’ energy spent by the person affected. It may be true that Polyjuice and Gillyweed produce or provide a certain amount of ‘cosmic energy’ and their effects wear off once that amount of energy is spent (I don’t think we can say for sure either way), but the person under the effect of the potion/plant are not described as spending any energy at all on sustaining their transformation. From their point of view, it just happens by itself and then undoes itself later on.

Answer (score 69):

## Transformed Animagi remain in animal form while asleep.

Animagi who are transformed can sleep and stay in their animal form. Scabbers, who’s really Peter Pettigrew, sleeps while around people, and has always remained a rat while asleep. Scabbers is actually shown sleeping, conclusively proving he stays in his Animagus form when sleeping.

> “Ron’s magic wand was lying on top of a fish tank full of frogspawn on the window-sill, next to his fat grey rat, Scabbers, who was snoozing in a patch of sun.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 3 (The Burrow)*</sup></sub>

In fact, Scabbers was known to sleep *quite a lot*, so it probably wasn’t hard for him to stay transformed then. If it was particularly difficult, he likely wouldn’t sleep in front of people so often.

> “Ron reached inside his jacket and pulled out a fat grey rat, which was asleep.
>
> ‘His name’s Scabbers and he’s useless, he hardly ever wakes up.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 6 (The Journey from Platform Nine and Three-Quarters)*</sup></sub>

It likely doesn’t take conscious effort to remain in Animagus form while already transformed, they seem to just stay in Animagus form until they actively transform (or are forcibly changed) back.

Comment: Sirius Black has also mentioned having spent so much time as a dog he almost forgot he could turn back. I don't remember where he said it though.

Comment: You should really use spoiler tags for this stuff.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman there’s a statute of limitations on spoilers - if you didn’t read Prisoner of Azkaban or see the movie at some point in the past SEVENTEEN years, you probably don’t care about plot spoilers…

Comment: @s3raph86 and others: [site policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/980/31394) is that **spoilers don't age** - we don't consider the age of the material when deciding what should be hidden as a spoiler. Anyone, regardless of age, could be reading any story for the first time now and not want to have it spoiled for them.

Comment: I don't have it in front of me to prove it, but I seem to recall Professor McGonagall asleep as a cat in the first chapter of the first book

Comment: @s3raph86 I just read the book last year. Further, kids not yet ready to read Harry Potter are surely many to come. At least think of the children.

Answer (score 25):

#### No, they wouldn't revert to human form

We know that Ron's pet rat Scabbers was actually an Animagus, Peter Pettigrew, in his animal form. He lived with the Weasleys for a number of years, and even slept in Ron's bed. If there was any chance of his reverting to human form while asleep he wouldn't have risked it, as the consequences for discovery were potentially fatal.

Comment: You should really use spoiler tags for this stuff.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman Why don't you edit it in? Poster of this answer may not check SE for the rest of the day.

Comment: I don't contribute much on entertainment stacks and don't know how you do spoilers.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman Start the paragraph with `>!`. Though an answer should stand on it's own merit without being entirely one spoiler block i.e. only hide what needs to be hidden.

Comment: @Korthalion Or I might disagree that there's a need for a spoiler tag in my answer. I considered it at the time of writing, decided that the answer would end up essentially being one big spoiler block, and chose not to include spoiler markup as a result.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist To be honest, that's not really your decision. If the community decides your answer needs a spoiler tag, the community will edit one in whether you want it there or not.
Not that I think this answer particularly needs one, but as a general principle...

Comment: @Korthalion As a general principle, the community doesn't get final say on the content of an answer, so that's not how that situation would actually play out.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It's not the content being changed, just a spoiler tag being added that has no structural effect on the content of your answer.
If that's really how it works (and I doubt it), it shouldn't work like that. How can we deal with real spoilers if the original answerer gets the final say in everything?

Comment: @Korthalion If people are that concerned about spoilers, they can not click on questions. The general policy, as far as I'm aware (and I could be wrong), is that we only really care about spoilers in *questions* (in particular their titles) because they're harder to avoid (e.g. they might appear on the Hot Network Questions list in the sidebar).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Hmm, could be worth a question on meta? I think it's good for the community to be able to censor spoilers without the answer owner's permission.